# function to compute and input average speed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 input fields, distance, time and average speed.  I would like the average speed field to be automatically computed to minimise user effort.  As such I have come up with this function but it doesn't work:

```
$('#Avg Speed').click(function(event) {
            var distance = $('#Distance');
            var time = $('#Time');
            var speed = distance / time;
            $(this).append(speed);
        });
```

Any ideas? Even better than clicking the field would be that the result automatically comes up once distance and time is completed.  No doubt my code reveals what a novice I am at this stuff.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? If you're using `<input>`s, it might be better to use a `blur` or `keyup` on the source fields rather than `click` on the target. Or at least `focus`.

Comment: there is not Speed tag in html or you cant have space in id

Comment: I'm using textboxfor:      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => input.ColumnWidthEditableProperties[i].Value, new { id = @input.ColumnWidthEditableProperties[i].Name})

Comment: Ah yes, there is a space in the id, duh!  I will look and report back

Answer (score 1):

If your speed is auto generated is good to make it disabled if it's input.
Also may be best event you search for is blur
HTML part:

```
<label>Distance <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance"></label><br />
<label>Time <input type="text" name="time " id="time"></label><br />
<label>Speed <input type="text" name="speed " id="speed" disabled></label>
```

Jquery part:

```
$('#distance,#time').on('blur', function() {
 var distance = $('#distance');
 var time = $('#time');
 var speed = $('#speed');

 if(parseInt(time.val()) > 0 && parseInt(distance.val()) > 0)
   speed.val(distance.val()/time.val());
 })
```

Also if it will be good a idea to add measures for times, distance and speed

Comment: thanks, this solution looks perfect in that the speed is auto generated. Unfortunately it is still not working for me, and I can't even get the event to trigger in the debugger. But I think this is there must be some other error in my code and will get an experienced friend to take a look with me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="Distance">
<input type="text" id="Time">
<input type="text" id="Speed">

$('#Avg Speed').focus(function(event) {
        var distance = $('#Distance').val();
        var time = $('#Time').val();
        var speed = distance / time;
        $(this).val(speed);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try with an onKeyUp event, i'll give you an example:

```
HTML:
   <input type="number" id="distance"></input>
   <input type="number" id="speed"></input>
   <input type="number" id="speed" onKeyUp="calcultate()"></input>
   <Label id="result"></Label>
JS:
   function calculate(){
    //get all input values calculate your thing and then put it back //in the result, this will be called each time a user presses a key in the //last input field
   $('#result').text(yourResult);  
   }
```